# Python Operator (+=) and SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, operators

Ok, what am I doing wrong?

```
x = 1

print x += 1
```

Error:

```
print x += 1
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Or, does `+=` not work in Python 2.7 anymore? I would swear that I have used it in the past.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`x += 1` is an [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) in Python.

You cannot use *statements* inside the print statement , that is why you get the syntax error. You can only use [*Expressions*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) there.

You can do -

```
x = 1
x += 1
print x
```

Comment: Thanks Anand. I should have caught that. :) On a side note, seems like you answer all of my questions.

Comment: Guess I just answer alot of question :) .

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend logically separating out what you're trying to do.  This will make for cleaner code, and, more often than not, code that behaves like you actually want it to.  If you want to increment x before printing it, do:

```
x = 1
x += 1
print(x)
>>> 2  # with x == 2
```

If you want to print x before incrementing it:

```
x = 1
print(x)
x += 1
>>> 1  # with x == 2
```

Hope that helps.